# How to add linear segments to ggplot in Interrupted segmented time series regression

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have fitted an interrupted time series regression to count data, and would like to display the results similar to this

[image: Time series]

Taken from: Lindstrand A, Bennet R, Galanis I, et al. Sinusitis and pneumonia hospitalization after introduction of pneumococcal conjugate vaccine. Pediatrics. 2014;134(6):e1528-36. doi:10.1542/peds.2013-4177.

Specifically, what I am trying (and failing) to reproduce is the added magenta, and cyan trend-lines respectively. I have been attempting to do this in ggplot. The problem is that my model is fit as `glm(family = poisson)` so that the coefficients are not on the original scale. Further complicating this is that I have supplied the at risk population as an offset i.e. `glm(count ~ ., offset(log(at_risk)), family = poisson, data = df)` but would like to display the data as `(count / at_risk)*1000` on the Y-axis.

```
set.seed(42)
int = 85
df <- data.frame(
    count = as.integer(rpois(132, 9) + rnorm(132, 1, 1)),
    time = 1:132,
    at_risk = rep(
        c(4305, 4251, 4478, 4535, 4758, 4843, 4893, 4673, 4522, 4454, 4351),
        each  = 12
    )
)
df$month <- factor(month.name, levels = month.name)
df$intv <- ifelse(df$time >= int, 1, 0)
df$intv_trend <- c(rep(0, (int - 1)),
                   1:(length(unique(df$time)) - (int - 1)))
df <-
    df %>%
    mutate(lag_count = dplyr::lag(count))

fit <- glm(
    count ~ month + time + intv + intv_trend +
        log(lag_count) + offset(log(at_risk)),
    family = "poisson",
    data = df
)
df$fit <- exp(c(NA, predict(fit)))


ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = (fit / at_risk) * 1000)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image: plot with lines drawn manually in]

(I have drawn the lines I want to be able to create into the resulting ggplot lineplot)

There is a continuous secular trend `time` that is given by the pseudo equation `count ~ intercept + B1 * time` which I would like to truncate such that it stops at roughly `time = 72`. This would be analogous to the magenta line in the above plot. An intervention `intv` occurs at `time = 85` which causes a change in level `intv` and change in slope `intv_trend`. The pseudo code for the line of the intv effect with respect to time is `count ~ intercept + intv + B1 * time + B2* intv_trend`, analogous to the cyan line above.

I have attempted `geom_abline()` with different versions of `exp(coef(fit)[1] ...` etc. but I can't get the line to even show in the plot.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You haven't set a seed, so the data frame is not reproducible. Also, it looks like you need a comma in your data frame code at the end of the `time` line. If you have a way of identifying the change point, you can add a column called, say, `group` and label the first part of the prediction line `Group A` and the second `Group B`. Then use `group` as a color aesthetic in your plot to get two different lines.

Comment: Fixed  the code as you pointed out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in my comment, if you have a way of identifying the change point, you can add a column called, say, `group` and label the first part of the prediction line `Control` and the second `Intervention` (or whatever labels you prefer). Then use group as a color aesthetic in your plot to get two different lines. In the code below, I've added the grouping variable manually. To get predictions on the scale of the data, add `type="response"` to `predict`.

First, set up the data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

int = 85
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
  count = as.integer(rpois(132, 9) + rnorm(132, 1, 1)),
  time = 1:132,  
  at_risk = rep(
    c(4305, 4251, 4478, 4535, 4758, 4843, 4893, 4673, 4522, 4454, 4351),
    each  = 12
  )
)

df$month <- factor(month.name, levels = month.name)
df$intv <- ifelse(df$time >= int, 1, 0)
df$intv_trend <- c(rep(0, (int - 1)),
                   1:(length(unique(df$time)) - (int - 1)))
df <- df %>%
  mutate(lag_count = dplyr::lag(count))
```

Create model and get predictions:

```
fit <- glm(
  count ~ month + time + intv + intv_trend +
    log(lag_count) + offset(log(at_risk)),
  family = "poisson",
  data = df
)

df$fit <- exp(c(NA, predict(fit)))

# Get predictions on the same scale as the data
df$fit2 = c(NA, predict(fit, type="response"))

# Add a grouping variable manually
df$group = rep(c("Control","Intervention"), c(72, 132 - 72))
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = fit2)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, aes(colour=group)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(colour="")
```

[image]